# Observer not filling in the field

Tags: laravel, observers

I've created an observer to complete the user_id when a user adds a new department.

The created method in the DepartmentObserver:

```
public function created(Department $department)
{
    //
    if (auth()->check())
    {
        $department->created_by_user_id = auth()->id();
        $department->save();
     }
}
```

The model:

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'deptname',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
    'created_by_user_id'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'created_by_user_id');
}
```

Then registered the obeserver in the AppServiceProvider Class

```
 public function boot()
{
    //
    Department::observe(DepartmentObserver::class);

}
```

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'created_by_user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `departments` (`deptname`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

I think the oberserver is not firing on the create event.  I also tried `composer dump` and `php artisan config:cache` 
and it didn't work. I'm on laravel 8 (Breeze, not Jetstream)

Comment: because the `created` event is fired AFTER it is "created"/saved ... not before

Comment: I ended creating a Trait. Works better